# Exposing SOAP 1.1 web service with WCF in ASP.NET 4.6

Tags: asp.net, wcf, soap, legacy-code, asp.net-4.6

We're using ASP.NET 4.6 (MVC & Web API) on our web site. Now we have the requirement to provide a "webhook" for an external service, and their client only supports SOAP 1.1 (and does not run .NET).

I've been trying to construct a WCF service that the external SOAP 1.1 can consume, using both programmatic configuration and Web.config configuration, but I can't get to a state where the service is actually usable from my own test client (generated with Visual Studio 2015).

All documentation seems to be inaccurate (for example, the information in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361(v=vs.110).aspx does not work; there is no "envelopeVersion" attribute any more) or for previous versions of Visual Studio or ASP.NET or WCF. Also, documentation seems to suggest that basicHttpBinding means SOAP 1.1, but that does not seem to be the case.

I am fine with not using WCF for this, but I don't know what to use instead. I'm not sure ASMX would solve the problem, if ASMX is even usable on ASP.NET 4.6.

All working service instances I've been able to provide still emit non-SOAP 1.1 namespaces or similar in the response, producing errors on the client side.

The only working solution I have currently is to use MVC or Web API and parse a HttpRequestMessage manually and returning manually crafted SOAP 1.1 responses, which is a very brittle hack.